# What is the expected value of the payment if T has exponential distribution with mean 5?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The initial value of an appliance is $700, and its future value is given by:

\begin{align}v(t)=100(2^{3-t}-1),&&0\leq t\leq 3.\end{align}
If the appliance fails in the first 3 years, the warranty pays $v(t)$.
what is the expected value of the payment on the warranty if $T$ has an exponential distribution with mean 5.

I got 
\begin{align}\int^3_0(100(2^{3-t}-1)\frac{1}{5}(e^{-t/5})\,dt.\end{align}
 I'm not sure if that's right though.

any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your expression for $E(v(T))$ as an integral is correct.

Comment: okay, great. I've been having trouble integrating it though. It's definitely not a nice integral.

Comment: It is slightly unpleasant to type, but not bad in principle. If after a while you are experiencing trouble, I can show how to do it.

Comment: That would be great. Thank you very much.

Comment: I've been working on this one since yesterday, and when I couldn't seem to integrate it, I thought I would post it here.

Comment: I tried using 2^(3-t) as e^((3-t)ln2).

Comment: Yes, that's how to do it. I slightly prefer $8e^{-t\ln 2}$ but your version has some advantages.

Comment: okay, thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. I have outlined the integral calculation.  Some unpleasant calculator work remains. You might ask Wolfram Alpha whether it agrees with the numerical answer you obtain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expression for $E(v(T))$ is correct. For the actual integration, we can write the integral as 
$$\int_0^3 20\cdot 2^{3-t}e^{-t/5}\,dt-\int_0^3 20e^{-t/5}\,dt.$$
The second integral is familiar. For the first integral, rewrite as 
$$\int_0^3 160 e^{-(\ln 2+1/5)t}\,dt$$
and make the substitution $u=(\ln 2+1/5)t$.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}
\int e^{-a t} \operatorname d t
 & = \int e^{u} \operatorname d (- u/a)
 & : t = - u /a
\\[1ex]
 & = c_1 - \frac{e^u}{a}
\\[1ex]
 & = c_1 - \frac{e^{-a t}}{a} & \tag{1}
\\[2ex]
\int b^{-t}e^{-a t} \operatorname d t
 & \int e^{-(a+\ln b) t} \operatorname d t
\\[1ex]
 & = c_2 - \frac{e^(-{a+\ln b) t}}{a+\ln b}
 & \text{using (1)}
\\[1ex]
 & = c_2 - \frac{b^{-t}e^{-a t}}{a+\ln b}
 & \tag{2}
\\[2ex]
\int_1^3 100(2^{3-t} - 1) \frac 1 5 e^{-t/5} \operatorname d t 
 & = 160 \int_1^3 2^{-t} e^{-t/5} \operatorname d t - 20 \int_1^3 e^{-t/5} \operatorname d t
\\[1ex]
 & \ddots
\end{align}$